# How can I insert multi rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert, row

I try to write the SQL code to enter the 1st 2 rows of data, based on the table shown below.
My code:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 ( 
    EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE 
)
VALUES (
    101, 'News', 'John', 'G', '08-Nov-00', '502'
);

INSERT INTO EMP_1 ( 
    EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE 
)
VALUES (
    102,'Senior', 'David', 'H', '12-Jul-89', '501'
);
```

But I keep get character error. I am using ms access 2007, ERROR" Charracter Found after end of SQL statement".

Comment: pls show more details of the error

Comment: Show us the error message and the datatype of each column.

Comment: Error "CHarracter Found after end of SQL statement"

Comment: I see your problem.. MS Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,You can insert multiple rows like this

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 
 ( EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
VALUES (
    101, 'News', 'John', 'G', '08-Nov-00', '502'
),
(
    102,'Senior', 'David', 'H', '12-Jul-89', '501'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you're using the SQL execution method which is processing only a single SQL command. You can combine the SQL and use just 1 'insert' command:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_1 ( 
    EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE 
)
VALUES (
    101, 'News', 'John', 'G', '08-Nov-00', '502'
),
(
    102,'Senior', 'David', 'H', '12-Jul-89', '501'
);
```

Error 'Charracter found after end of SQL statement' is described here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760224.aspx

Comment: It said missing ";"when I save my query.